# Can not import Iterm2's color scheme

Tags: iterm2

I'm new to Mac OS X and installed the iterm2 , But I can not import the color scheme which downloaded from github,the error message poped up like this:

The selected file could not be read or did not contain a valid color scheme.

I'm pretty sure that I've downloaded the right file,so I really don't understand what happend.

Comment: can you post the contents of the file you're trying to import?

Comment: No bother. I've changed some other schemes and it works. I've delete those import-failed scheme so I can not recur the problem, I'm sorry. But I think shellbye's solution will work. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: I only ask because I accidentally saved the link to the file in github (which is the HTML for the file) rather than cloning the repo or grabbing the raw version (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/altercation/solarized/master/iterm2-colors-solarized/Solarized%20Dark.itermcolors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by open and check the downloaded .itemcolors file and find that it is not in the right format. I did this to fix it:

#### 1.export the current:

> Command+i -> switch to Color -> Load Resets -> Export

#### 2.modify the exported file:

open it in text editor, and then goto [this repo](https://github.com/JamieMason/All-iTerm-Colors) in github, pick what you like according to [this](https://github.com/JamieMason/All-iTerm-Colors/issues/2). Remeber, just replace what inside the outtest  not the whole file. Save it.

#### 3.import the file you just saved.

> Command+i -> switch to Color -> Load Resets -> Import
> chose the file you saved, and that's all

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't really understand the way '.itermcolors' works, now I see. I can't recur the problem because I've forgotten where I found those schemes, but I think I can handle it by your method if it occurs again.

Comment: @namco Thank you for the accept, that means a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

shellbye's solution works for me. In addition, if you'd like to persist the color scheme out of this particular session, you may want to go to Preference->Profile and set the color scheme over there.

Answer (score 0):

When saving the theme file get rid of the .txt that is there by default & save as all files. Then you should be able to import the file. This worked for me, I am on a mac.